# Biblatex-Chicago: Double-underline and overlong title issues

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, ulem

I'm using LaTeX to typeset my senior thesis (undergrad) and we're required to cite in Chicago style.  I've installed `biblatex` to use the chicago style, and run into the following issues.

1. All the underlined titles in the bibliography and footnote citations are showing up as double-underlines.  I have no idea what to do.  Does anyone else have this issue?  Any ideas on how to fix?  For reference, I'm running MikTeX 2.8 on Windows 7 and using the latest edition  of `biblatex` & the corresponding `biblatex-chicago` package.  I'm using `notes-chicago`.  I am using the `ulem` package as well.
   `
2. LaTeX does not break up long titles, resulting in ridiculous overfull hboxes.  I've checked the `.bib` file and gotten rid of double {}, but the issue persists.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The simplest solution is to tell your professor that underlining is simply a way to indicate *italics* when people used typewriters, and since you can produce italics correctly, you don't need to underline anything. Then don't load the `ulem` package, and both problems disappear.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to tell your professor that underlining is simply a way to indicate italics when people used typewriters, and since you can produce italics correctly, you don't need to underline anything. Then don't load the `ulem` package, and both problems disappear.

Answer (score 4):

To support Alan's answer —too long for comment— *Chicago 16* (i.e., the current edition) says on the use of emphasis:

1. Section 2.14 - "underlining will generally be construed by publishers to mean italics";
2. Sections 7.47-76 describe the ways in which phrases text may be treated specially in running text, enumerating italics, scare quotes, special capitalisation, and bold faces as the possibilities for picking out emphasis and italics, nowhere suggesting the use of underlining for this purpose;
3. Section 13.8 describes the sole recommended use of underlining - "Underlined words in a quoted manuscript may be printed as italics, unless the underlining itself is considered integral to the source".

A couple of asides: first, underlining is widely accepted for preparing copy to be typeset by someone else, although with the near ubiquitous use of sufficiently capable software, this use is fairly rare these days.  Also, note that *Chicago* does not recommend the use of typewriter fonts for such things as code or URL in running text, although they are appropriate in set off blocks such as code listings.