# Underlined titles in bibliography with biblatex and ulem packages

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, text-decorations, ulem

I want to underline all titles in a bibliography using the `biblatex` package with Biber backend and the `ulem` package. `biblatex` seems to break `ulem`'s line breaking capabilities. Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Super, Max},
        title = {An extraordinary long and meaningless example book title, but unfortunately not correctly wrapped}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{MWE.bib}
    \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\uline{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is there any workaround? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To compose bibliographies are two different styles that you should not mix: **one** is based on the typewriter that besides monospaced types, makes use of quotation marks and underlined in the absence of other typographic marks. The **other style** is **typographic** and makes use of italics, bold and small caps to achieve the same effect. Since `LaTeX` allows you typographic high quality results, should be consistent with them and ignore those more limited solutions inspired by the typewriter. It is not an answer, it's just an observation and suggestion.

Comment: Beyond matters of style, do not understand why `biblatex` is not able to split a long text with a command like `\uline{...}` and it is possible with `\emph{...}`, `\texttt{...}` etc. But `ulem` used out of `biblatex` is able of splitting.

Comment: we need an expert in `biblatex`.

Comment: @Aradnix I don't want to initiate a discussion about style.

Comment: @skpblack This is exactly the question that came to my mind.

Comment: Having read both [Biblatex-Chicago: Double-underline and overlong title issues](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16857/35864) and [References in margins `biblatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70851/35864), I think this is a known issue, but, alas, with no solution I could find.

Comment: The `\texttt`, `\emph` and `\textbf` commands just choose another font in LaTeX, while `\uline` does something quite different to get the output right. Maybe the way `biblatex` prints the bibliography makes one of those methods to get the output right yield incorrect results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found two ways. Using `\usefield` (biblatex.pdf, page 177)

**First way:** Redefine `bibmacro{title}`

The `bibmacro{title}` is defined in the file biblatex.def as follows:

```
\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

I redefine the `bibmacro{title}`, in the preamble, as:

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext{%
     \printtext[titlecase]{\usefield{\uline}{title}}%
     \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
     \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Super, Max},
        title = {An extraordinary long and meaningless example book title, and fortunately correctly wrapped},
        subtitle={A short subtitle},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext{%
     \printtext[titlecase]{\usefield{\uline}{title}}%
     \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
     \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

**Second way**: Using `\DeclareFieldFormat`

I found other form using `\DeclareFieldFormat` and it is not necessary redefine the `bibmacro{title}`.

The format used in the `\printfield{title}` is `titlecase` (In the definition of `bibmacro{title}`). Then must be redefined this format. This is important because I use `\currentfield` and it is defined only when used `\printfield`, not with `\printtext`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{
    \ifdef{\currentfield}
      {\ifcurrentfield{title}
         {\usefield{\uline}{\currentfield}}%
         {#1}}
      {#1}}
```

The `\ifdef{\currentfield}` is to avoid troubles if the format `titlecase` is used by a `\printtext`, for example.

The `\ifcurrentfield{title}` is to apply the format only to the `title` field.

Finally, if you would like remove the default emphasis in the `title`, it is necessary redefine the `title format`, used by `printtext`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Super, Max},
        title = {An extraordinary long and meaningless example book title, and fortunately correctly wrapped},
        subtitle={A short subtitle},
        year={2004},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{%
    \ifdef{\currentfield}
      {\ifcurrentfield{title}
         {\usefield{\uline}{\currentfield}}%
         {#1}}
      {#1}}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to implement the second solution proposal and it works perfectly! Thank you very much for all your efforts in elaborating and documenting solutions!

Comment: In case someone has problems with proceedings or journals, it helps to replace 

"\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}"
with 
"\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets from the ulem documentation that might explain what you are seeing:

> Unlike regular underlining, ulem allows line breaks, and manual
>   hyphen- ation, within the underlined text; but it is far from perfect.
>   It is most suit- able for simple text like LATEX: A document
>   preparation system that may need to be underlined in a manuscript
>   submitted for publication. Again, ulem can only give underlined text
>   for \em when the text is delimited by explicit braces.

and:

> Every word is typeset in an underlined box, so automatic hyphenation
>   is disabled, but explicit discretionary hyphens (-) will still be
>   obeyed. Several text-formatting commands are specially supported
>   within the un- derlining: -, \ , ~, \, \newline, \linebreak,
>   \nolinebreak, \penalty, \hskip, \hspace, \hfil, \hfill, \hss.
>   Displayed math is not supported. The special commands do have a
>   problem: they end a group so any local assignments are lost.

and:

> One important incompatibility with braces and macro replacement: All
>   the text in braces or coming from a macro is typeset in a box (as if
>   in \mbox). Consequently, braces will suppress stretching and
>   line-breaking in the text they enclose. Moreover, the
>   specially-handled commands -, \, \newline and \linebreak are usually
>   ignored if they appear inside extra braces. They operate only when the
>   braces delimit a command parameter without introducing a level of
>   grouping. (Even though braces delimiting command parameters do not
>   normally imply grouping, many commands will add their own grouping.)
>   Thus, you should try to limit inner braces to short bits of text or
>   for delimiting parameters to commands. For emergency repairs, see the
>   sadistic ‘Marat/Sade’ example below. Syntactical spaces inside braces
>   never cause a problem, nor do spaces in math mode.

This documentation can be found as a link to a PDF from here:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem

I came across a similar problem with underlining in a different situation.  The solution I ultimately came up with, which was barely acceptable for me and may not be acceptable to you, was a kludge a found that cycles through the text to be underlined and treats each word separately.  This means that each word is underlined  but not the spaces between the words.  In a bibliography format this may not be appropriate.

The kludge looks like this:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This odd bit plucks words individually
%from a group and undelines each word
%this allows for word-wrapping which otherwise
%does not work well.  The trade off is that
%spaces between words are not underlined
%
\makeatletter
\def\mboxed#1{%
    \@mboxed#1 \@empty
}
\def\@mboxed#1 #2{%
  \uline{#1}\space  % underline from package ulem
   \ifx #2\@empty\else
    \expandafter\@mboxed
   \fi
   #2%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

(I wish I could take credit for that bit of code or even give proper credit to the actual author, but I can't find the link that lead me to it.)

Which I implement in my situation like this:
\newcommand{\role}[1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem){\mboxed{#1}}

I have very little knowledge, unfortunately, of Biblatex, so I'm don't know how or even if this solution could be of any value to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the efforts connected with it. While your workaround allows at least the single words to be underlined, it is a bit disturbing that the blank spaces are not. In this sense, I prefer the solution of @Carlos Lanziano above. Anyway, thank you very much for your detailed answer!