# How do I get a line break after the title with biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, line-breaking, biber, biblatex-chicago

I tried looking at the documentation for this, but it gave me nothing but grey hairs.

MWE (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200997/underlined-titles-in-bibliography-with-biblatex-and-ulem-packages)):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Super, Max},
        title = {The Title of the Book},
        publisher = {Foo Books},
        year = {2016},
        note = {my note},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image: Current result]

What I'm looking for is:

[image: Desired result]

`\ldots{}` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest way to put a newline in this case is to add newline to the begining of "notes".

The following definition is how to do for only books:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{note}{\newline%
  \ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}}%
```

The following definition will do it for all notes:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\newline%
  \ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}}%
```

You can add this definition to your MWE as given below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Super, Max},
        title = {The Title of the Book},
        publisher = {Foo Books},
        year = {2016},
        note = {my note},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{note}{\newline%
  \ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}}%

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this solution will only work if a `note` field is present.

Comment: @moewe: Yes. You need to add more checks to the macro, as per the requirement on other fields too.

Comment: Mhhh, yes. Conceptually, adding the `\newline` to a field format will always have this problem: the format is only executed if the field is actually present. Plus, you can't know which field is the first non-empty one after the `title` block.

Comment: Thanks. I marked it as the correct answer in spite of the problems that others pointed out.

Comment: Getting hacky, but it seems you can fix the empty field problem by adding a line with `note = {~},` to the bibliography.